# Randomize dictionary sorting

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, dictionary

I have been thinking this through but I did not come to any conclusion (not that great with Python yet).

My dictionary looks like this:

`{1: [dog, animal], 2: [square, shape], 3: [red, color]}`

I am printing out the values but the dictionary is sorted by numbers, which is fine but I want to randomize it so I print out something like this:

```
3
red
color
1
dog
animal
2
square
shape
```

I know that list would be more ideal for this situation but this data is from existing structure that I cannot change. Maybe re-numbering the keys would do the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries are *already* listed in arbitrary order, they do not have a fixed order. See [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-arbitrary) Any sense of order is a coincidence and depends on the insertion and deletion history of the dictionary.

That said, it's easy enough to further ensure a shuffled list with `random.shuffle()`:

```
import random

items = yourdict.items()
random.shuffle(items)

for key, value in items:
    print key
    print '\n'.join(value)
```

Comment: Nice! You can use os.linesep for platform-agnostic line separator :)
+1 for the link

Comment: @ReutSharabani: when writing to a text file, newlines are already translated for you. When using `print` you don't need to use platform-specific line separators either.

Comment: well ... to be fair, _arbitrary_ is not the same as _random_.

Answer (score 4):

You can randomize the keys:

```
import random
....
keys = dictionary.keys()
random.shuffle(keys)
for key in keys:
    print key, dictionary[key]
```

Comment: I would do `keys = list(dictionary)` to make it forward compatible.

Comment: can you elaborate? python.org uses `keys()` in the note about `items()` and nothing is said in `keys()` itself...

Comment: in python3.x, `keys` returns an object which is a lot more `set`-like.    IIRC, it doesn't support the indexing which is required by `random.shuffle`.  `list(d)` gives the same thing that `d.keys()` gave in python2.x.